# Scrollable Context Menu Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, contextmenu

I'm having an issue where I'm populating my Context Menu dynamically by pulling data from a database. However, the context menu overflows upwards off the screen.

Is there a way to either make it scrollable or have the context menu populate downwards instead of upwards?

[image]

This is my file:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from UltimateDropDown import UltimateDropDownApp
from Database import Database
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database()
    db.populateChangeTypes()
    kv = """
#: import HoverLabel HoverBehavior
#: import ContextMenu kivy.garden.contextmenu

UltimateDropDown:

<UltimateDropDown>:
    id: layout

    ModifiedHoverLabel:
        id: hover_label
        pos: 10, self.parent.height - self.height - 10
        text: "Left click anywhere outside the context menu to close it"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        on_enter: context_menu.show(*app.root_window.mouse_pos)

    Button:
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8 }
        size: 300, 40
        text: "Click me to show the context menu"
        on_release: context_menu.show(*app.root_window.mouse_pos)

    ContextMenu:
        id: context_menu
        visible: False
        cancel_handler_widget: layout
"""
    str_list = []
    for item in db.changeTypeToId:
        str_list.append("""
        ContextMenuTextItem:
            text: """ + '"{0}"'.format(item) + """""")
    kv += ''.join(str_list)
    Builder.load_string(kv)
    udda = UltimateDropDownApp()
    udda.run()
```

The only code that is relevant here is the Kivy Garden Context Menu (from GitHub).

**Additional Note**: Context Menu looks fine if under 20 items. Starts populating upwards when I overflow.

Comment: Have you considered breaking the `ContextMenu` into submenus?

Comment: I have not. I just started Kivy so I was hoping to find an easier solution to spring from.